# Accessing multiple UIButtons at the same time created in IB

Tags: iphone

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access a group of UIButton created in Interface Builder.

I created a single IBOutlet and point that outlet in each of UIButton in the XIB. Now my problem is how can I change the properties of this UIButtons such as changing its title when everytime I click a single another UIButton?

Thanks alot.

sasayins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple buttons share a single IBOutlet.  You need one IBOutlet for each.